# How to use Nested Views in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hi I am trying to understand the best practise to use nested views.

I have an 'Attribute' View which is bound to collection of name value pairs in the view model. I need to reuse this at various places in my UI.

I have another 'Condition View' which has a string property and Dictionary(string,string) collection. I tried to create a text box and add the Attribute View control in the XAML

```
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="{x:Static l:StringResources.ConditionViewLabelText}" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Type,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" />
        </StackPanel>
        <vw:AttributeView />
    </StackPanel>
```

I want to bind the AttributeView's bound property to the Dictionary(string,string)'s collection property of the parent view model. Whats the best way to do it. I am not able to bind the vw:AttributeView to a ConditionViewModels ?

Can you please let me know the best practise to do this?

-- EDIT Please find my AttributeView (This is the child view's xaml code). The data template is bound to an observable collection on the AttributeViewModel

```
 <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllAttributes}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                        <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding KeyValue, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <Button Width="50" Content="{x:Static l:StringResources.AttributeViewButtonDeleteText}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteAttribute, ElementName=AttributeControl}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name}"></Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Button Name="btnSomething" Content="{x:Static l:StringResources.AttributeViewButtonAddText}" Command="{Binding AddNewAttribute}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You need to supply a bit more information here, can you please show your ViewModel code, especially the relationship between the two view models.

Comment: Hi ColinE (Thanks for the reply), My two ViewModels are not related at all currently. Should the View hierarchy be replicated in the ViewModel level too. As In should the Parent View's view model have a pulbic property of type Child view's viewmodel.

Comment: Hey there was one answer for my question but it got deleted. Strange :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments that your parent / child relationship is not reflected in your view model, you have two options:

1. Create the relationship in your view model to reflect the relationship in your view, allowing you to navigate from the parent to the child and vice-versa should you need this.
2. Use a [RelativeSource FindAncestor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx) binding to navigate up the visual tree and locate a control bound to the parent view model, biding to this controls `DataContext`.

Option (2) will make you look clever, but option (1) is much simpler!

Comment: Thanks ColinE, I will try the first approach and post back if it works or doesnt work!!

Comment: Hi ColinE, for achieving the Option1, should I put the vw:AttributeView inside a Item template and set the Data context of this ItemTemplate to the child Viewmodel property? Would that be a right way to achieve the option 1 you said