# Is there a way to create a multiple page form in a single page?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to stack overflow and WPF, so be patient with me please. I am developing an app in WPF, and in one of the pages I need to create a form to receive user input. I would like to divide this form into sections(somewhat like multiple pages in google forms) where the user clicks on a "Next" button to go to the next questions, while giving them the ability to go back to previous questions if need be. I know this is possible by making multiple pages and loading them into a frame whenever the user clicks a button but is there a way to create the whole form in a single page, and if there is, how would I do so? Thank you in advance.

I imagine there is way to do it by playing with element visibility, but I am fairly new to WPF and I am not entirely sure how I would go about doing that, or even if it is the better option.

---

**Edit**

First page of the form, as soon the user answers the question and clicks the button "Proxima"(Next), they are sent to the next page of the form:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The second page of the form. The user can either go back to edit previous answers by clicking on the button "Voltar"(go back) or they can finish the form by clicking on the button "Enviar"(Send).
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

If possible and ideal, I would like to have the code for forms 1 and 2 on the same xaml file, is there a way to do that?

---

**Edit**
Found my solution, I created the pages on separate grids and made a C# sharp code to change their visibilities by clicking buttons as seen below:

xaml
[!enter image description here][3]][3]

---

C#

```
public partial class CharacterCreation
    {
        public CharacterCreation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int previous=0,next=0;

        private void btnNextClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (next == 0)
            {
                gridFirstPage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                gridSecondPage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                btnPrevious.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                next = 1;
            }
            else if (next == 1)
            {
                gridSecondPage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                gridThirdPage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                next = 2;
                previous = 1;
            }
            else if (next == 2)
            {
                gridThirdPage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                gridFourthPage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                next = 3;
                previous = 2;
            }
            else if (next == 3)
            {
                gridFourthPage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                gridFifthPage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                next = 4;
                previous = 3;
                btnNext.Content = "Done";
            }
            else if (next==4)
            {
                //open new page
            }
        }

        private void btnPreviousClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (previous == 0)
            {
                gridFirstPage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                gridSecondPage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                btnPrevious.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                next = 0;
            }
            else if (previous == 1)
            {
                gridSecondPage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                gridThirdPage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                next = 1;
                previous = 0;
            }
            else if (previous == 2)
            {
                gridThirdPage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                gridFourthPage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                next = 2;
                previous = 1;
            }
            else if (previous == 3)
            {
                gridFourthPage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                gridFifthPage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                next = 3;
                previous = 2;
                btnNext.Content = "Next";
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Thank you all for the helpful answers!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQCJQ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhRWA.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdkyU.png

Comment: basically, this is called a "subview" at least as far as i know, if that can help on your searches. As always, there are multiple ways to do it; simple example taken at random: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198646/how-to-use-nested-views-in-wpf-mvvm

Comment: I am sorry, but I am quite new to WPF and coding in general, could you give me a basic rundown of how to implement a subview? I seem to be unable to understand what is being said in the post you linked

Comment: There are different way to do it. Just to name a few: you can make use of a TabControl without a header (and control it with previous/next buttons), or use a ContentControl and change its content. If you say you are new to WPF, take the easiest one. Your approach with hiding all other pages but one is a viable option too. Use the `Collapsed` value to hide other control. Your question, as it is now, is too broad. Start implementation, and if you face some problems, please ask a more specific question, showing what you have tried.